# Is there an iPad app that lets me share my iPad screen with someone at another computer at another location?

Tags: ipad

Is there an iPad app that lets me share my iPad screen with someone at another computer at another location? I'd like an app that lets me write stuff with my stylus (like note taker HD) and have that appear on someone else's screen on a computer at another location. If there is no such app, I'd be happy with some hack that lets me do this through my computer. (Now what I tend to do is write a bunch of stuff and have note taker HD email it to the other person.)

Comment: Is jailbreaking an option?

Answer (score 1):

There's a Mac app called [AirServer](http://www.airserverapp.com) that enables you to mirror your iPad 2 onto your Mac. Maybe from there you can get this to another location...

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to share live drawing on your iPad and nothing else, Air Sketch is a good app. You launch the app and it provides you with a local IP and port to type into a web browser, and your drawing on the iPad will show up live.

Links: [Air Sketch](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/air-sketch/id376617790?mt=8) ($9.99) [Air Sketch Free](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/air-sketch-free/id376796733?mt=8) (Free, obviously)

Also: while this only tells you to use a local IP (192.168.X.X:8080), I have not tested using a global IP with it. It may or may not work for this purpose.

Comment: It should work remotely as long as everything is set up correctly such as port-forwarding.